# Generic algorithm implementation to select a random subset

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, c++14, generic-programming

Suppose we are to select a random subset of size `m` from a total set of size `n`. Since each element in the total set can be identified using a unique index from `S = {0, 1, 2, ..., (n - 1)}`. The problem is equivalent to randomly select `m` distinct elements from `S`.

A trivial algorithm would be repetitively invoking a pseudo-random number generator `rand` to generate random numbers from `S`. If a number has been generated before, just try again. The algorithm terminates until `m` distinct numbers are generated. This algorithm has an optimal space complexity of `O(1)`, but may invoke `rand` more than `m` times.

I'm more concerning about the time complexity instead of space complexity, and would happily trade space for time if reasonable. So I implemented the following algorithm. It invokes `rand` exactly `min{m, (n - m)}` times, but at the price of an increased space complexity of `O(n)`. (original code can be found [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/hhxx/algorithm.hpp#L122))

```
template <typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
auto tick_count() {
  return Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
}

template <typename OutIt, typename RAND = std::minstd_rand,
          typename Uint = typename RAND::result_type>
void random_subset(std::size_t m, std::size_t n, OutIt it, RAND&& rand =
                   RAND(static_cast<Uint>(tick_count()))) {
  assert(n - 1 <= rand.max());
  assert(m <= n);
  if (m == 0) return;
  auto swapped = false;
  auto tmp = n - m;
  if (tmp < m) {
    m = tmp;
    swapped = true;
  }
  std::vector<std::size_t> indices(n);
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), static_cast<std::size_t>(0));
  auto back_it = indices.end();
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    auto idx = rand() % (n - i);
    std::swap(indices[idx], *--back_it);
  }
  swapped ? std::copy(indices.begin(), back_it, it) :
            std::copy(back_it, indices.end(), it);
}
```

I'm wondering whether the algorithm can be further improved in terms of performance. Improvements to the generic implementation are also welcome.

Comment: Why not using something like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since I'm generating random numbers from `0..(n - 1)`. A basic URNG would just be sufficient.

Comment: @Lingxxi can you set a limit on n? Can you specify in advance the range n can be [n_min, n_max]?

Comment: Are we trying to reinvent [`std::experimental::sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/sample)?

Comment: Also, I'm tempted to downvote this for the `% (n - i)` hack alone.

Comment: @T.C. Yes. It's not exactly accurate when `(rand.max() + 1) % n != 0`. But this is not expected to be used in serious scientific applications anyway. So, I trade this little accuracy for performance and simplicity.

Comment: @tinky_winky It may be [0..1M] for typical use, I would say.

Comment: If the n_max was small enough then what you could do would be to populate vector of all combinations C(m,n) in advance and return randomly one of them. There would be just one call to randomization routine per each call of algorithm. Unfortunately n_max = 1000000 is much too much.

Comment: @T.C. Guess I will have to use `std::uniform_int_distribution` anyway to be exact.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right. I will have to use `std::uniform_int_distribution` to be exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a very minor variant of the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for random shuffling, specifically the [second variant of the Durstendfeld version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm):

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−2 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j < n-i
     exchange a[i] and a[i+j]
```

Just change the loop termination from *n - 2* to what you need.

In the proof, the loop invariant is that once an index *i* has been passed, the array up to it is a random shuffle. Consequently, you may terminate early with your required result.